# using selectize.js with Aurelia and systemjs

Tags: jquery, aurelia, systemjs, selectize.js

I'm trying to use [Selectize](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) with aurelia and keep getting the error:

*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function(…)*

I have jquery being loaded via script tag in the index.html, and trying to load selectize in a simple component:

EventForm.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label for="eventTitle">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="eventTitle">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="eventType">Sport</label>
        <select id="eventType">
            <option>Event 1</option>
            <option>Event 2</option>
            <option>Event 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

EventForm.js

```
'use strict';
import 'jspm_packages/github/selectize/selectize.js@0.12.1/dist/js/standalone/selectize';

export class EventForm {
    constructor(){

    }

    attached() {
        $('#eventType').selectize({
            create: true,
            sortField: {
                field: 'text',
                direction: 'asc'
            },
            dropdownParent: 'body'
        });
    }
}
```

index.html

```
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspm_packages/npm/jquery@2.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
.
.
.
```

I have a feeling that this has more to do with systemjs loading, but have tried loading selectize in the index.html with the same results. Could someone help point out what I'm doing wrong? Using jquery 2.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `jquery`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34772020/3436921

About `selectize`: just check the map in `config.js` for selectize, I suppose you need to import it like `import "selectize"` or `import "selectize.js"`

Comment: Everything is correct and selectize is loading it just doesn't extend the jquery elements prototype as expected

Comment: My example is working recommended way for using jquery and jquery plugins, I think you need to load not standalone version, but `/dist/js/selectize.js` which is loaded when you just `import "selectize.js"` or `import "selectize"` depending on the name of your jspm package